# Avoiding buggy/jerky animation

Tags: matlab, animation, 3d, matlab-figure

I have this code here below. It basically rotates a box in 3D. I know I can rotate the camera using `camorbit` but I actually want to rotate the object, not the camera around it. So the strategy is to create an element in so(3) and take the exponential map to SO(3) as the element is varied continuously over time.

```
% Create object

 yo = unique([-1 -1 -1; perms([1 1 -1]); perms([1 -1 -1]); 1 1 1], 'rows');
 yo2 = delaunay(yo(:,1), yo(:,2), yo(:,3));
 box=tetramesh(yo2, yo);

% Create prescribed rotation

seedMat=skewdec(3,1)*skewdec(3,2)*skewdec(3,3);         % so(3)
t=linspace(0,20,500);
r=zeros(1,4,length(t));
reqTraj=zeros(3,3,length(t));

for i=1:length(t)
    reqTraj(:,:,i)=expm(seedMat*t(i));                  % SO(3)
    r(:,:,i) = vrrotmat2vec(expm(seedMat*t(i)));        %Axis angle form
end

% Freeze axis

axis vis3d
axis([   -2    2   -2    2   -2    2])

% Rotate

for i=1:length(t)
rotate(box,r(1,1:3,i),r(1,4,i))
pause(0.001)
end
```

My question is why is this animation jerky? Is there something that I can do to fix it?

**EDIT:** Changing the last part as follows, made the buggy/jerky behavior go away, but resulted in an entirely new rotation behavior. So i am not sure if it is the correct approach or not. Can someone comment?

```
% Rotate
for i=2:length(t)
rotate(box,r(1,1:3,i),r(1,4,i-1)-r(1,4,i))
pause(0.001)
end
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the axis you're rotating around, `r(1,1:3,i)`, wobbles/jerks around. The reason for it may be the way you generate it, `vrrotmat2vec(expm(...`. I have not had any experience using these functions, so I cannot tell what exactly is the problem, but if you replace `r(1,1:3,i)` with some constant vector, say `0.5*[1,1,1]` there is no wobble.

Comment: or even `rotate(box, rand(1,3) , r(1,4,i) )` is not that wobbly. Do you need to have a defined trajectory or you were just trying to get a random one ?

Comment: I need a repeatable defined trajectory.